# Excel conditional formating columns based on formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight a row based on the current week (dynamically) by filling the cell(s) with a blue color. So if the current week changes to 3 then the third row should be blue.
My spreadsheet would look like this:

`Current date 15-07-2021 ;=TODAY()`
`Current week 2 ;=ISOWEEKNUM(A1)`

| Weeknumber | Availability |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 days |
| 2 | 3 days |
| 3 | 1 day |
| 4 | 1 day |
| 5 | 4 days |

Does anybody have any thoughts on this matter?

Thanks! SQLShane

Comment: How is the current week 2? `ISOWEEKNUM` returns the week number in the *year*. Did want week num in the month?

Answer (score 0):

- Select relevant area (here: `$A$2:$B$7`)
- Choose Start/Conditional Formatting/New Rule/Formula
- Enter `=$A2=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())` (A2 must be the active cell of your selection).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Qualia! The conditional formatting only works per row and not per column, see screenshot below. How could I make this work per column?
![Valid XHTML](https://ibb.co/17mSXrh)

Comment: @SQLShane: It depend on which part of the comparison cell you define as fixed ($). In my example the column was fixed. In your example, you would have to absolutely address the row instead. Select `C4:F9` with `C4` being the active cell. Then you set the following formula: `=C$3=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())`.